# How to get Deployments ($ kubectl get deployments) by specifying custom property value?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have deployed a Kubernetes service and when I query to get the Deployment `$ kubectl get deployments`, I can see the Deployment. 
the `json` of the Deployment looks like below --

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
        release: testRelease
        customProp: xyz
```

My question is how can I frame a query by which I can get the Deployment by specifying the **'customProp'** value. Does `kubectl` support to pass a jsonpath as part of the query? so that I can pass a `json` path like `jsonpath='{$.spec.template.metadata.labels.customProp}'` and value against this jsonPath as **'xyz'**.

This is what I am thinking to execute:

```
$ kubectl get deployments -n <namespace> <json path query>
```

However not sure how to frame the `json` path query and pass along with `$kubectl get deployments`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kubectl does support [query feature](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/), you can use below query

```
kubectl get pods --selector=customProp=xyz
```

Kubectl also supports JSON path expressions too, to get more details, follow the [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#viewing-finding-resources). You can write query following the syntax shown on the link.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one can query to the `kube-apiserver` for a resource using jsonpath. Run following command to get what you want:

```
$ kubectl get deploy test -o=jsonpath='{.spec.template.metadata.labels.customProp}'
```

For more usage, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath.

Comment: -o is used for output, my question was how to query based on the value of the 'customProp'.

Comment: @GautamMoulik In your statement it was hard for me to understand that you wanted to get your resources by filtering with labels. You also mentioned `jsonpath`, by which you can't do that too. And `jsonpath` is only for output as far as i know. Also `fieldselctor` has limitation to filter resources depending on resource kind. You can't use any field in `fieldselector` for all resources. So you should clarify your needs more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Add a label to your deployment object. Then with below command to query specific deployment
kubectl get deploy - l labelname=labelvalue

Answer (score 0):

To get deployed image name as a string, you can choose from any attribute in deployment yaml.

```
   kubectl get deploy/${image.name} -o jsonpath="{..image}"
```